# Check if Profile name is contained in Tagged Profile names: added link

Tags: performance, django

I have a function which checks for a profile name and determines if it is in a tagged profile name.

```
def check_profiles(request):
try:
    # get all individual profiles
    profiles = Profile.objects.all()
    # get all individual tagged profiles
    tagged_profiles = TaggedProfiles.objects.all()
    # ids to exclude in adding dates
    exclude_profiles = []
    # for profile in profiles
    for profile in profiles:
        # for tagged in sdn list
        for tagged_profile in tagged_profiles:
            # if contains 1
            if any(name in tagged_profile.name_breakdown() for name in profile.name_breakdown()):
                # put in exclude
                exclude_profiles.append(profile.pk)
                profile.status = 'FOR REVIEW'
                profile.save()
                break
    

    for profile in Profile.objects.all().exclude(pk__in = exclude_profiles):
            cleared_dates = profile.cleared_dates
            cleared_dates.append(
                {
                    'date': datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
                    'time': datetime.now().strftime('%I:%M %p')
                })
            logger.debug(cleared_dates)

            profile.cleared_dates = cleared_dates
            profile.save()
        
except Exception as e:
    logger.error(e)
```

Basically, if a profile's name is `'firstname lastname'`, it's breakdown is `['firstname', 'lastname']`. And if `tagged_profiles` include either a `'firstname'` or a `'lastname'` in any of it's breakdowns, it's a hit.

But I'm doing it very inefficiently. How may I optimize it with any of django's built in functions?

You can see it [here](https://www.online-python.com/NxH6svWAOJ).